# Thread safety in parameters passed to a static method

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, parameters, thread-safety

Assuming a static method like below is called from ASP.NET page,
can a different thread(b) overwrite the value of `s1` after the first line is executed by thread(a)?

If so, can assigning parameters to local variables before manipulation solve this?

```
public static string TestMethod(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
   s1 = s2 + s3;
   ....
   ...
   return s1;
}
```

Is there are a simple way to recreate such thread safety related issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, under some condition, as seen by the example code.

```
public static class ConsoleApp {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Write something.");
        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return;

        new Thread(() => TestMethod(null, str, "")).Start();

        // Allow TestMethod to execute.
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        unsafe {
            // Grab pointer to our string.
            var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            var strPtr = (char*)gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();

            // Change it, one character at a time, wait a little more than
            // TestMethod for dramatic effect.
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i) {
                strPtr[i] = 'x';
                Thread.Sleep(1100);
            }
        }

        // Tell TestMethod to quit.
        _done = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Boolean _done;
    public static void TestMethod(String x, String y, String z) {
        x = y + z;

        while (!_done) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), x);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Requirements (afaik)

1. Unsafe context to use pointers.
2. Use String.Concat(String str0, String str1) which is optimized for cases where `str0 == String.Empty` or `str1 == String.Empty`, which returns the non-empty string. Concatenating three or more strings would create a new string which blocks this.

---

Here's a fixed version of your modified one.

```
public static class ConsoleApp {
    private static Int32 _counter = 10;

    public static void Main() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var str = GetString();
            Console.WriteLine("Input: {0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), str);
            new Thread(() => TestMethod(str)).Start();

            unsafe {
                var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                var strPtr = (char*)gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
                strPtr[0] = 'A';
                strPtr[1] = 'B';
                strPtr[2] = 'C';
                strPtr[3] = 'D';
                strPtr[4] = 'E';
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static String GetString() {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = _counter; i < _counter + 10; i++)
            builder.Append(i.ToString());

        _counter = _counter + 10;
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static void TestMethod(Object y) {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Output: {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), y);
    }
}
```

This still works because Object.ToString() is overriden in String to return this, thus returning the exact same reference.

Answer (score 4):

No, the parameters are local variables - they're independent of any other threads. As strings are also immutable, you're safe. If these were mutable - e.g. a parameter of `StringBuilder s1` - then although the *value* of `s1` (a reference) couldn't be changed, the object that the parameter referred to could change its contents.

`ref` and `out` parameters could potentially have issues, as they can alias variables which are shared between threads.

Comment: Thanks.. Parameters are local variables and independent of other threads. But is there are simple way to recreate / debug such issues?

Comment: @Pkay: Not usually, I'm afraid. Threading bugs are tricky to track down and test :(

Answer (score 1):

I had same confusion too and here is my test code. Just sharing it ...

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadTest b = new ThreadTest();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadTest.sum));
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadTest.sum));
        t.Start(10);
        t1.Start(12);

    }
}

class ThreadTest
{

    public static void sum(object XX)
    {
        int x = (int)XX;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("max : " + x + "  ---  " + i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

... Now if you run this you will see that int x is safe. so local non static variables are safe for a process and can not crippled by multiple thread

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon, here is the my evaluation on this. 
In the following code, i spawn threads simply using Thread.Start and the output becomes inconsistent.

This is proving that string passed on to a method can be modified.

If otherwise please **explain**!

```
public static class ConsoleApp{

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static int counter = 10;

    public static void Main()
    {            
        string str;

        object obj = new object();
        // Change it, one character at a time, wait a little more than
        // TestMethod for dramatic effect.            
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                str = GetString();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TestMethod, str);
                new Thread(() => TestMethod(str)).Start();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetString()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        lock (obj)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = counter; i < counter + 10; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(i.ToString());
                temp = i;
            }
            counter = temp;            
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void TestMethod(object y)
    {   
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), y.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code I pasted proved that a passed string can be changed using pointers. Your changes introduce a lot of new oddities, like locking on local objects and closure problems when capturing str to pass to your TestMethod. Also, you totally removed the code I wrote that actually changed the string.

Comment: Thats right Simon, I infact derived this code from yours. The whole problem is that the output from the above code is not as expected. Can you throw some light on it?

Comment: What are your expectations? 1) Remove all locks, they have no effect. 2) Declare str inside your for-loop. This fixes a closure problem where the same string is used several times. 3) Add the unsafe code block inside your for-loop which changes the already passed string. I've done these three steps and added the result to my answer.

Comment: I got it.. I did not understand the closure problem. Thanks for pointing it out.